# How to overrwrite access control section with @IsGranted for controller method in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I use Symfony 4.

I have `^/admin` only for the role `ROLE_ADMIN`. However I need some pages to be accessible for other roles. For example, I want `/admin` and `/admin/article` to be accessible for the role `ROLE_ASSISTANT`. I started from added `@IsGranted("ROLE_ASSISTANT")` to `/admin/article` controller method. But it did not help. I can not find any resources about how to overwrite access control in `security.yaml` but I do need. I do not need to open whole admin section for assistant, just a couple of pages in admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to overwrite it from controller. Just change the order of access_control in your security.yaml file. Something like:

```
access_control:
   - { path: ^/admin/article, roles: ROLE_ASSISTANT }
   - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: The question is how to overwrite `access_controle` with `@IsGranted`. I do not want overfill `services.yaml` with lots of rules hard for understanding. My example is pretty simplified and real case is more complicated.

Comment: @FreeLightman the Firewall will already have blocked your Request, before it even reaches your `isGranted`, if the `access_control` already denies access. So this solution is - IMHO - the most appropriate one. Alternative being allowing `access_control` for both roles and filtering in all relevant controllers/routes, which is probably way more error-prone.

Comment: So it is a common practice to use `access_control` and not to use `@IsGranted`? I thought they could be combined.

Comment: @Jakumi have reason. It is possible to use IsGranted inside your controller but not really clean. Controller have just to receive a request and send a response. In other hand, security component have to handle for everything about security, it is called 'separation of concerns"

Comment: The docs explain access_control: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html You can use IsGranted to further restrict what access_control lets through but your can't widen it.  If you have more complex rules and special cases then may you own request listener and possibly some voters might be the way to go.